# Dropdownlist loads visually blank(correctly populated) even with selected Item set

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have a DropdownList that is written blank in the frontend:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="cod_req_interessado" runat="server" CssClass="form-control w-auto" ClientIDMode="Static" DataValueField="cod_interessado" DataTextField="cpf_cnpj_nome_formatado"></asp:DropDownList>
```

And is populated in the codebehind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim listaProcuracao = BO.clsInteressadoProcuracao.CarregarInteressadosComProcuracaoAtiva(cod_usuario_externo)
  If listaProcuracao.Count = 0 Then
     cod_req_interessado.Visible = False
  Else
     If Not IsPostBack Then
        Dim interessadosOutorgantes = From a In listaProcuracao Select New With {.ID = a.Outorgante.cod_interessado, .Name = a.Outorgante.cpf_cnpj_nome_formatado}
        cod_req_interessado.Items.Clear()
        cod_req_interessado.DataTextField = "Name"
        cod_req_interessado.DataValueField = "ID"
        cod_req_interessado.DataSource = interessadosOutorgantes
        cod_req_interessado.DataBind()
     End If
  End If
End Sub
```

IT IS POPULATED CORRECTLY AND EVERYTHING WORKS.

The problem is when rendered in browser, the select element APPEARS like it has a blank item selected, even when there are no blank items and first item populated on codebehind is selected:
[image]

I have already tried setting the `SelectedIndex = 0` after the `Databind()`
I also tried reworking how the list is populated(looping thru the datasource and inserting items manually)

Again, everything works, including sending the form does use the selected item's value correctly and no error occurs. But I want the item to appear on the select box from the start. Items appear correctly on changing.